# Operating a function through a list of df

Tags: r, list, apply, purrr

I am sure there are 1.000 approaches to perform what  I need to do, but I am stuck the way I am going to do it.
I have a list of 268 dfs (after using split function) corresponding to each variable to analyze

You can see there are 4 columns (id, name(variable), 1 and 3). I need to compare 1 and 3 with paired t.test, but before I want to merge or bind rows by id. Knowing that k is the list of dfs, I have tried to bind rows by id and then paired t.test

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(50203027, 130108009, 140102095, 
70713002, 60901028, 70111024, 140101091, 120715029, 50521002, 
110104024, 140103030, 60901027, 140103036, 110104030, 60901035, 
50109025, 50203016, 110606061, 50527001, 120715035, 140103030, 
50203017, 120715020, 50508027, 140103035, 50203032, 70713001, 
50508026, 50203029, 140102089, 110606056, 50203032, 50521001, 
50203006, 50203019, 50203030, 50203022, 111201006, 71801002, 
111201006, 71801001, 130104004, 130105044, 140102087, 120715027, 
140101097, 50203026, 60901028, 130106038, 50203015, 50203013, 
60901038, 120715012, 140103020, 50203011, 110104019, 60901029, 
110104019, 110113008, 110104023), label = "Identificador", format.spss = "F10.0", display_width = 10L), 
    name = c("ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1"), `1` = c(2.184, 
    0.567, NA, 1.297, NA, 0.782, NA, NA, 4802.075, 0.7, NA, 0.552, 
    NA, 1, NA, 1.411, 1.697, NA, NA, 0.984, NA, NA, 0.771, NA, 
    NA, 0.715, NA, NA, 1.104, NA, NA, NA, 0.868, NA, NA, 0.883, 
    0.941, NA, NA, 0.715, NA, 1.254, 0.698, NA, NA, 1.072, 1.023, 
    1.519, 1.134, NA, NA, NA, 0.81, 0.348, 0.608, 0.5, 1.329, 
    NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(NA, NA, 0.744, NA, 1.111, NA, 0.751, 
    1.119, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.68, NA, NA, 1.456, 0.895, 
    NA, 1.261, 0.943, NA, 1.17, 1.223, NA, 1.232, 2.103, NA, 
    1.008, NA, 0.855, NA, 0.895, 0.841, NA, NA, 1.054, NA, NA, 
    2.922, NA, NA, 1.087, 1.406, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.523, 0.534, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.143, 1.343, 1.112)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df1 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(50203027, 130108009, 140102095, 
70713002, 60901028, 70111024, 140101091, 120715029, 50521002, 
110104024, 140103030, 60901027, 140103036, 110104030, 60901035, 
50109025, 50203016, 110606061, 50527001, 120715035, 140103030, 
50203017, 120715020, 50508027, 140103035, 50203032, 70713001, 
50508026, 50203029, 140102089, 110606056, 50203032, 50521001, 
50203006, 50203019, 50203030, 50203022, 111201006, 71801002, 
111201006, 71801001, 130104004, 130105044, 140102087, 120715027, 
140101097, 50203026, 60901028, 130106038, 50203015, 50203013, 
60901038, 120715012, 140103020, 50203011, 110104019, 60901029, 
110104019, 110113008, 110104023), label = "Identificador", format.spss = "F10.0", display_width = 10L), 
    name = c("ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", 
    "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1", "ABCG1"), `1` = c(2.184, 
    0.567, NA, 1.297, NA, 0.782, NA, NA, 4802.075, 0.7, NA, 0.552, 
    NA, 1, NA, 1.411, 1.697, NA, NA, 0.984, NA, NA, 0.771, NA, 
    NA, 0.715, NA, NA, 1.104, NA, NA, NA, 0.868, NA, NA, 0.883, 
    0.941, NA, NA, 0.715, NA, 1.254, 0.698, NA, NA, 1.072, 1.023, 
    1.519, 1.134, NA, NA, NA, 0.81, 0.348, 0.608, 0.5, 1.329, 
    NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(NA, NA, 0.744, NA, 1.111, NA, 0.751, 
    1.119, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.68, NA, NA, 1.456, 0.895, 
    NA, 1.261, 0.943, NA, 1.17, 1.223, NA, 1.232, 2.103, NA, 
    1.008, NA, 0.855, NA, 0.895, 0.841, NA, NA, 1.054, NA, NA, 
    2.922, NA, NA, 1.087, 1.406, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.523, 0.534, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.143, 1.343, 1.112)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As I said I had them in list

```
my_list <- list(df, df1)
```

Then I combine rows by id (not sure if there is another option)

```
df %>% group_by(id,name) %>% summarise_all(na.omit)
```

Now I want to apply it through the list of dfs, but ERRORS all the ways to it.
I don't know how to iterate correctly through list of dfs

```
z<-sapply(my_list, function(x){ x %>% group_by(id, name) %>% summarise_all(na.omit) })
```

I am not sure how to approach this: this way throw an error

```
z<-sapply(my_list, function(x){ my_list[x] %>% group_by(id, name) %>% summarise_all(na.omit) })
```

Maybe with purrr function but it is not working

My goal idea is to reach the following format in all dfs contained in the list and being able to iterate

```
         id name    `1`   `3`
      <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1  50203022 ABCA1 0.795 1.71 
2  50527001 ABCA1 0.681 1.07 
3  60901023 ABCA1 2.35  2.76 
4 110606061 ABCA1 0.627 0.791
5 140101088 ABCA1 0.698 1.49 



t.test(.$`1`, .$`3`, paired =T)
```

Thanks in advance

PD: the previous step before the split data is like this. Maybe is easier for sb doing it this way

````
df3 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(110104019, 111201026, 140103027, 
120715025, 140103020, 110104028, 110110005, 111201006, 50118001, 
110104019, 60901038, 120715030, 50203032, 50521002, 50203020, 
130102014, 50203017, 120715019, 110113006, 110113007, 50203010, 
120715026, 50203006, 50203008, 70201047, 120715037, 110113007, 
140103019, 70111023, 60901031, 70713001, 130105044, 111201006, 
50203015, 111201007, 140102089, 70802012, 71801002, 50109025, 
140103019, 110104027, 120715021, 60901024, 130102008, 70710002, 
50203022, 71801003, 70802015, 140101088, 111201026, 140101097, 
50203010, 50521001, 50203026, 120715035, 60901037, 50203029, 
140102087, 60901033, 50203010), label = "Identificador", format.spss = "F10.0", display_width = 10L), 
    name = c("iapoespinr", "iapoa1_1", "iohtyru", "hii_pf_i", 
    "hdl_intcol_r", "iapoe_spinreact", "hdl_smallcol", "CD36", 
    "efl", "lcat", "ldlox_basal_r", "ldlox_oxr_r", "hdl_pe", 
    "hdl06", "col_abdp", "lcat", "ldlox_max_r", "hdl_smallcol", 
    "iapob_sr", "ief_shsy5y", "hdlaox_i_oxr", "in_tyru", "ippy", 
    "IDO", "IDO", "hdl_3col", "TGFB2", "IL23A", "NAMPT", "LRP1", 
    "hdl_vd_pf", "iapocii_spinreact", "albu_hd", "PPARD", "IL23A", 
    "ldlox_lag", "RXRA", "hdlaox_i_max_r", "apoa2", "il6_IFM", 
    "pon", "NR1H2", "hdl_largecol", "itrig", "NFE2L2", "iscd36", 
    "pafah_reus", "NAMPT", "c3_sr4", "TGFB2", "crea", "ihomocis", 
    "c24_1n9", "itrig", "iapob_sr", "hdl05", "itasst", "in_tyru", 
    "CYP27A1", "hdl05"), row = c(36761L, 47121L, 72303L, 52371L, 
    70416L, 38983L, 40386L, 45126L, 2923L, 37069L, 26142L, 54395L, 
    13938L, 16687L, 10389L, 59719L, 9604L, 50313L, 42286L, 42801L, 
    6004L, 52714L, 4182L, 4666L, 29353L, 56932L, 43095L, 69830L, 
    28325L, 23260L, 32008L, 60612L, 45172L, 8196L, 45398L, 68133L, 
    33141L, 35530L, 1139L, 69947L, 38600L, 50955L, 20022L, 57041L, 
    31137L, 10985L, 35860L, 34433L, 64614L, 46912L, 65796L, 5706L, 
    16281L, 11489L, 56029L, 25848L, 12247L, 66966L, 23727L, 5742L
    ), `1` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.78770632102, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0.98445094361, NA, 1.8886174427982, NA, 39.9, NA, NA, 
    NA, 111111, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.232, NA, NA, NA, 0.691, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.07, 1.11, NA, 1.484, NA, 28.52, NA, NA, 
    0.73, 13.5042, 82, 1.451, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.494, 0.93, NA, 
    NA, NA, 111111, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10.7), `3` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    1.12438625204583, NA, 0.04, NA, 1.482, 1.1518772323, 11.701896673, 
    NA, 1.1349806704, NA, 23.4, NA, NA, 0.98599700241, NA, NA, 
    NA, 555555, NA, NA, NA, 0.522, NA, 1.747, NA, 1.778, 1.175, 
    NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.85112903806, NA, NA, 39184.058353, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.365, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    11.2, NA, NA, 1.63, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -60L)) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

With `sapply/lapply`, when we call the lambda function, the `x` is the list element.

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(my_list, function(x){ 
    x%>%
     group_by(id, name) %>%
     summarise_all(na.omit) 
})
```

Here we are using `lapply` instead of `sapply` as `sapply` by default uses `simplify = TRUE` and thus it returns a matrix like object with elements as list

---

If we want to use `purrr` (in addition `_all/_at` are deprecated in favor of `across`)

```
library(purrr)
map(my_list, ~ .x %>%
    group_by(id, name) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), na.omit), .groups = 'drop'))
```

Comment: Both approaches work perfectly.

Comment: But I don't understand why this approaches yield different object in terms of memory usage. Furthermore when you perform identical(x, y) = FALSE

Comment: @JavierHernando `identical` will be FALSE if there is any attribute that is a mismatch.  You may check with `all.equal` with `check.attributes=FALSE`